# ASP.NET Identity missing fields

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-identity

Under new `ASP.NET Identity tables` I cannot see some of the fields i.e. **IsApproved**, **LastActivity** and etc...

Have we use profile and create custom code to manage those fields?

I.e. here ?

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
        if (user != null)
        {
            await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);

            // Use profile field and update it... ???      
            user.LastActivity = DateTime.Now;
            UserManager.Update(user);

            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Your model is a type of `LoginViewModel` not the Domain model. Domain model may have those fields and auto updating for you.

Comment: @Kaf Well... How to switch to another model? Whats the different between them? Thank you in advance for your answer and put it here so I can vote it.

Comment: FYI, Mr. Kent, "ASP.NET" is a single word, no spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UserManager.FindAsync returns the type that was passed into it when it was initialized. So in this instance I'm assuming that the type of user in `var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);` is `IdentityUser`. So in the constructor of your AccountController you would be passing in a UserManager and setting it to a local property. You need to change IdentityUser (and all the associated code) to whatever you custom profile is. e.g.

```
    public class CustomUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public DateTime LastActivityDate { get; set; }
        public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
    }

    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        public UserManager<CustomUser> UserManager { get; set; }

        public AccountController() : this(new UserManager<CustomUser>(new UserStore<CustomUSer>()))
        {

        }

        public AccountController(UserManager<CustomUser> userManager)
        {
            UserManager = userManager;
        }

        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                CustomUser user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
                //now we have access to the custom fields added.
                user.LastActivityDate = DateTime.Now;
                UserManager.Update(user); // Update DB field
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

As per comments, by looking at the code, it seems you are doing a [Model View ViewModel (MVVM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) pattern. That is great !

In MVVM pattern, there are two models. Domain Model (DM) represents the database model and ViewModel (VM) is for the view. DM contains all the schema related data for the database and VM has user validations, error messages etc for the view. Because of that your VM does not (or may not) have all the database fields. You just need what you need to pass to the user in the VM.

You can add more fields to the VM as per the requirement.